# Excel vba finds a range but cannot activate it

Tags: excel, find, range, vba

I am working with a database extract file in xlsx format. The structure looks like

```
ID     DC1      DC2 ............  DCn
1      data     data ...........  data
2      data     data ...........  data
3      data     data ...........  data
```

I use this code to find and activate the ID cell.

```
Set foundSourceRange = Sheets(sourceSheet).Cells.Find(What:=sourceColumn, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
foundSourceRange.Activate
```

Find gives the requested cell but Activate throws as error.

```
Runtime Error 1004
Activate method of Range class failed.
```

If I go to the extract file and edit the headers (retype them manually)
then my code works as expected. I have already tried to change an extract file format to csv but it gives the same error. Is there anything I can do with the code to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to activate the sheet first:

```
Set foundSourceRange = Sheets(sourceSheet).Cells.Find(What:=sourceColumn, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
Sheets(sourceSheet).Activate
foundSourceRange.Activate
```

You can only `.Activate` a range on the `ActiveSheet` object.